# " fields stored in the db can't have . in them."

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I try to rewrite this mongodb query (that works in command line):

```
db.projects.update({"tools.name" : "gitlab"}, {"$set" : {"tools.$.status" : "error"}})
```

in java:

```
DBObject queryUpdate = new BasicDBObject("tools.name", "gitlab");
queryUpdate.put("$set", new BasicDBObject("tools.$.status", "error"));
projects.update(null, queryUpdate, false, true);
```

I need to update every status if the tools name is "gitlab".

My collection looks like this (I put only one document for testing):

```
[{
_id: {
    $oid: "531f0e4dd14c366cef214fe7"
},
tools:[
    {
        name: "gitlab",
        url: "https://url/",
        status: "success",
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: "svn",
        url: "https://url/",
        status: "error",
        selected: true
    }]
}]
```

I think I'm really missing something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the update query only updates one document (the first matched).  You will  need to set the [multi](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html#update%28com.mongodb.DBObject,%20com.mongodb.DBObject,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) flag to true.

Also the update query in your statement is incorrect.  You should try:

```java
DBObject querySelect = new BasicDBObject("tools.name", "gitlab");
DBObject queryUpdate = new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("tools.$.status", "error"));
projects.update(querySelect, queryUpdate, false, true);
```

**Note:** The [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) positional operator matches only the first element within the array.  So, if you had multiple elements within the "tools" array with name="gitlab", only the first element will be updated.

Comment: Thanks. I already try this, but the problem is near DBObject queryUpdate = new BasicDBObject("tools.name", "gitlab"); I got this error “ fields stored in the db can't have . in them.”

Comment: There's an error in your update statement.  I've updated my post with the fix.  Try it out.

Comment: I've added another note.  Review that too.

Comment: Yea, but in my case i'll had only 1 element with "name"="gitlab". Thanks again :)

Comment: No issues then.  Just wanted to highlight how "$" operator works, as the fact that it matches only the first element is often overlooked.